# AuthenticationEntryPoint don't handle LockedException

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

The AuthenticationEntryPoint only handle InsufficientAuthenticationException.
I must handle LockedException to get the error message with custom message.
But if I verify the exception given to the entry point it is of class InsufficientAuthenticationException. I dont throw the LockedException. I should throw it from any filter?
The code is:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;

            ErrorResponse errorResponse = ApiExceptionHandler.createErrorResponse(status)
                    .error("Authentication Error")
                    .message(e.getMessage())
                    .build();

            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
            objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
            String errorJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorResponse);

            PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
            printWriter.println(errorJson);
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
    }
}
```

My spring security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final DatabaseUserDetailsService databaseUserDetailsService;
    private final DatabaseUserDetailsPasswordService databaseUserDetailsPasswordService;
    private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final SecretKey secretKey;
    private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    public SecurityConfiguration(@Lazy UserService userService,
                                 DatabaseUserDetailsService databaseUserDetailsService,
                                 DatabaseUserDetailsPasswordService databaseUserDetailsPasswordService,
                                 CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint,
                                 SecretKey secretKey,
                                 JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.databaseUserDetailsService = databaseUserDetailsService;
        this.databaseUserDetailsPasswordService = databaseUserDetailsPasswordService;
        this.customAuthenticationEntryPoint = customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderBean())
            .userDetailsService(databaseUserDetailsService)
            .userDetailsPasswordManager(databaseUserDetailsPasswordService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderBean() {
        CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider(userService);
        customAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        customAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(databaseUserDetailsService);

        return customAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/robots.txt",
                "/manifest.webmanifest",
                "/sw.js",
                "/offline.html",
                "/icons/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/styles/**",
                "/frontend/**",
                "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtUsernamePasswordAuthFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig,
                    secretKey))
            .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(secretKey, jwtConfig), JwtUsernamePasswordAuthFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, Mappings.USER).permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }

}
```

Comment: `LockedException` extends `AuthenticationException`

Comment: Why all the custom jwtfilters, spring security already has a built in jwtfilter